# Will my app consume more memory and battery if I keep a service Idly running?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a service for sending regular GPS location updates to a server.

Now, when someone is tracking their trip with the App the will loose connectivity many times for significant periods of time. If app is not connected to internet it just persists the GPS data and sends it later when we are connected. I have registered a `BroadcastReceiver` to get connectivity change updates.

Is it better for memory and battery to start the service when online and stop when offline, or is it better to keep the service running idly doing nothing until we are connected to internet?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545187/android-is-it-better-to-start-and-stop-a-service-each-time-it-is-needed-or-to-l) is a very similar question, but the answer was written 6 years ago, also my service would just be sleeping most of the time its not connected to internet, I wonder if in that case instead of starting/stopping the service around 5-6 times an hour, just keeping it running would be better.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not doing any processing when you don't have connectivity then it's not awful to have the service running. You should look into Reto Meier's stuff about making a background service as efficient as possible. He has a lot of really great tips.